# Can't ping a router's interface which is in a WAN directly connected to my router- (Packet tracer)

Tags: router, wan, ping, cef, packet-tracer

Here s a pic from packet tracer

[image]

What I'm trying to do is to ping Router3's Se2/0 interface from PC0.(Or Router2's Se2/0 interface from PC1)

However the ping message gets only as far as the Router2's Ethernet interface 
Shouldn't the ping work since ROUTER3's serial interface is connected to the WAN, which is directly connected to ROUTER2?

Some configuration info

PC0

IP : 195.10.10.2
Default gateway: 195.10.10.1

Router2

Fast Ethernet interface IP: 195.10.10.1
Serial interface IP: 195.10.30.1

Router3

Serial interface IP: 195.10.30.2

Subnet Masks are all 255.255.255.0

Comment: Does router 3 have a route back to PC0's subnet in its table?

Comment: you mean routing table?

Comment: Yes. If router 3 doesn't have a route back to PC0 then it can't successfully respond to any echo requests (pings) from PC0. If router 3 has a default gateway that is not router 2, then it needs an explicit route back to the network that PC0 is on. And likewise for Router 2 talking to PC1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all that You have route from PC0 to PC1 doesn't mean that You have route from PC1 to PC0.

**Thats are Zinin’s 3 routing principles:**

1. "Every router makes its decision alone, based on the
   information it has in its own routing table.“
2. "The fact that one router has certain information in
   its routing table does not mean that other routers have the same
   information.“
3. "Routing information about a path from one network to
   another does not provide routing information about the reverse, or
   return path."

That means all routers must have full routing table to all networks - R1 to networks beyond R3 and R3 to all networks beyond R2.

Besides R3 probably don't have any information about networks at the other site of R2. You can check it showing R3 routing table - `show ip route`

Answer (score 0):

You can set a static route in R2 towards the network that PC1 is in and another one in the reverse at R3.
Like so:
on R2: ip route (PC1's network address) (subnet mask)  195.10.30.2
on R3: ip route 192.10.10.0 255.255.255.0 195.10.30.1

After that you should be able to ping PC-PC and the s2/0 interface as well.